# Training and test accuracy plot shows strange behavior

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to build decision tree classifier for binary classification problem. My dataset was unbalanced (1=173 and 0= 354) and I used the resample approach to increase minority class and make them balanced. I build a model using gridSearchCv and here my code

```
x=df_balanced["x"]
y=df_balanced['y']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split( x, y, stratify=y, random_state=42,test_size=0.25)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer',CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
    ('classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])


grid = {
    'vectorizer__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
    'vectorizer__analyzer':('word', 'char'),
    'classifier__max_depth':[15,20,25,30]
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=grid, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
grid_search.fit(X_train,Y_train)
print(grid_search.best_estimator_,"\n")

best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
for param_name in sorted(list(grid.keys())):
    print("\t{0}: {1}".format(param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
y_pred=best_model.predict(X_test)

confusion=confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
report=classification_report(Y_test,y_pred)
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(Y_test, y_pred)
roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
print("Confusion matrix \n",confusion,"\n")
print("Classification_report \n ",report,"\n")
print("Train Accuracy",accuracy_score(Y_train, best_model.predict(X_train)))
print("Test Accuracy:",accuracy_score(Y_test,y_pred))
print("roc_auc_score",roc_auc)
```

and the output.

```
Confusion matrix 
 [[82  7]
 [13 75]] 

Classification_report 
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.86      0.92      0.89        89
           1       0.91      0.85      0.88        88

   micro avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       177
   macro avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       177
weighted avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       177


Train Accuracy 0.9510357815442562
Test Accuracy: 0.8870056497175142
roc_auc_score 0.8868105209397344
```

To check if I fail in overfitting problem I calculated the train and test accuracy, and I think I am not too much overfitting.

Then I plot the depth of tree that may lead to overfitting.
the code

```
 #Setup arrays to store train and test accuracies
dep = np.arange(1, 50)
train_accuracy = np.empty(len(dep))
test_accuracy = np.empty(len(dep))

# Loop over different values of k
for i, k in enumerate(dep):

    model=best_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

    #Compute accuracy on the training set
    train_accuracy[i] = model.score(X_train,Y_train)

    #Compute accuracy on the testing set
    test_accuracy[i] = model.score(X_test, Y_test)

# Generate plot
plt.title('clf: Varying depth of tree')
plt.plot(dep, test_accuracy, label = 'Testing Accuracy')
plt.plot(dep, train_accuracy, label = 'Training Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Depth of tree')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
```

The plot is very strange and I can not explain it.

[image]

Any help Plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking closely at your `for` loop, you will realize that you always just fit the *same* model; the following line:

```
model=best_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

does not depend in any way from your `k` and does not affect at all the `max_depth` parameter, as you actually intend to do.

Consequently, all the values of your (training & testing) accuracy are the same, hence the "strange" straight lines (i.e. constant values).

What I guess you want, is to get the performance metrics for the best parameters you have found from your CV and different depths; but the issue here is that `max_depth` is already included in your `best_parameters`, so your methodology looks rather vague...